# how to handle ajax calls with large data

Tags: ajax, json

I am using ajax call to call my webmethod written in C#.net from client side,
My method returns array of my entity class.
I am just testing how much amount of data i can show on my client side.
For this testing i hv added my data in loop. when i run loop for 1000 times, there are 1000 rows displayed in my jquery datatable. 
But when i run my loop for 10000 times success method of my ajax call is not getting called :(
can any one help me in the same.
Below mentioned is my code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'DynamicData.aspx/GetData',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                renderTable(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                $('#errorMessage').text(errMsg);  //errorMessage is id of the div
            }
        });
```

in above code when i run my loop for 10000 times my renderTable function is not getting called.

Comment: Error messages? You are probably exceeding the asp.net max response length.

Comment: There is no failure event, it should be `error`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a complete function to see if you are timing out or some other error is happening:
If it is a timeout, add a timeout property to the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'DynamicData.aspx/GetData',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: (10 * 1000),     // if timeout is a problem increase it here
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
            renderTable(response.d);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            $('#errorMessage').text(errMsg);  //errorMessage is id of the div
        },
        complete: function(jq, status) {
            // status = one of "success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"
            if (status != 'success') {
                $('#errormessage').text(status); 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't he just change the failure function to `error`, its correct specification?